# How to know whether its a tablet or phone using Appium?

Tags: appium

Is there any way to know if I am launching my tests against a tablet or a phone?
I have found several ways to determine the answer but for android developers. I need to know it launching my appium tests.

Thanks

Comment: If you know your tests are running on some tablets and phones, you can just get the UDID and run your specific tests in those UDID's

Comment: Did you get the answer?

Answer (score 0):

If it is about the screen resolution, you can always find this one by checking:

element.getLocation().getX() 
element.getSize().getWidth()

Besides, why you need to have it checked programatically ?

Comment: Because I have differents id for the same elements if they are displayed in a phone or in a tablet. I want to use the same code, and knowing if it is a tablet/phone looking for the correct id.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done it is by adding a custom attribute to your definition of the device (I use Protractor framework for my tests). For example:

```
{
   // iPhone 6s 
   seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:8105/wd/hub',
   browserName: 'safari',
   platformName: 'iOS',
   platformVersion: '8.4.1',
   deviceName: 'iPhone 6 Plus',
   udid: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
   deviceType: 'iPhone' 
},

{
   // iPad Mini 
   seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:8106/wd/hub',
   browserName: 'safari',
   platformName: 'iOS',
   platformVersion: '8.4.1',
   deviceName: 'iPad Mini',
   udid: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
   deviceType: 'iPad' 
},
```

Then, in my JS code I fetch the deviceType as follows

```
// This function will return true if the device under test is phone
isPhone: function() {
    if ( browser.deviceType === "iPad" ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
},
```

You can do the same for Android devices.

Hope it helps